# Same OS (Windows 10) twice in Dell BIOS boot sequence

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

Just as the title says, in a way or another I have got two boot options in my boot sequence which both point to the same boot file but have different names. In the past there only was the "Windows 10" option, but after a recent operation with GParted there had appeard the third option, which in fact points to the same OS as the first one.

The operation in GParted mentioned above: some time ago I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an external HDD, but due to lack of experience the installation wasn't configured properly and the result was that Ubuntu was using the EFI partition of my internal SSD to boot instead of an own EFI partition on the external HDD. I wanted to solve this, because I wanted to keep the two separated and eventually wanted to be able to boot the external HDD on another computer too. So I copied the EFI partition from the SSD to the beginning of the HDD, assigned the flags it needed and then removed the Ubuntu files from the first EFI partition and the Microsoft files from the second EFI partition (because I obviously didn't need those anymore on the mentioned drives) with the terminal in the GParted image.

Everything works just fine, but then there's this frustrating thing that the "UEFI: SK hynix SC311 etc." option always reappears in the boot sequence, even if I delete it from the firmware settings. I have also tried to remove both "Windows 10" and "UEFI: SK hynix etc." options, and they both reappeared at the next reboot.

Here are the pictures of my screen for further clarification (I don't know how to make a screenshot outside the OS). And please excuse the exagerated width, but I'm new here and I don't know how to make images smaller.

[image: Windows 10]
[image: UEFI: SK hynix SC311 SATA 128GB, Partition 1]
[image: Dell boot sequence]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EFI supports two kinds of boot entries:

1. User-configurable entries that can point to any bootloader on the EFI System Partition,
2. Automatic entries that are generated if an appropriately-named file exists on that partition. For x86-64 systems the file would be `EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi` (case-insensitive because it's FAT).

The 2nd variant was originally intended for bootable external media (CDs, USB etc.) that's supposed to be bootable without additional configuration. But it's also used on fixed drive ESPs because some EFI implementations are buggy and/or incomplete. One example is Virtualbox's EFI, which forgets all user-configured boot entries when a VM is powered off. In such cases having an always-present automatic entry as a last resort is convenient.

If you're willing to sacrifice some portability to get rid of the extra entry, deleting or renaming `EFI\Boot` from the ESP should do the trick. Note that it may get recreated by whatever you're booting though.

Comment: It's also used on fixed drive ESPs because it allows easily moving the OS disk to another machine -- you can't literally carry the NVRAM contents over to the new machine, but you can boot from EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi and use the OS itself to re-create the real boot entry. The same also happens to be convenient for in-place converting an OS from CSM to UEFI, e.g. I think Windows' `mbr2gpt` relies on this behavior.

Comment: @gronostaj I still don't understand how the UEFI firmware will still be able to boot if I delete `EFI\Boot` when this is where the most important files of the ESP are stored. Will the ESP still be bootable after I delete them? And what exactly do you mean by "If you're willing to sacrifice some portability"? What is the disadvantage of this solution?

Comment: @InnPalz All necessary Windows files should be in `EFI\Microsoft`. But as always, make backups and make sure you can restore them before doing anything risky. Regarding your other questions, I believe I've explained it in the longest paragraph. Basically presence of `EFI\Boot\BootX64.efi` generates a bootable entry on any EFI-compatible system without manual configuration.